# Why isn't cloudsql using all resources for a query?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

I have a query that I'm running on a cloudsql instance. It is the only query being run at that time and its taking 1.5 hours to run. When I look at my dashboard, I'm seeing that CPU never climbs over 20% and my read/writes never climb over 10% of their limit.

Why is the instance not using all resources available when there is no other load on the instance?

Comment: It’s probably using 1-2 CPUs and spending most of the time sorting/filtering/matching data it fetches from disk, not just reading/writing. If you add `explain` before the query, it will show you how it plans to tun it. If you add `explain (analyse, buffers)` it will run it and tell you how each part of that plan went exactly. Even if you have more CPU cores on the instanse and even if you adjust `max_worker_processes`, `max_parallel_workers` etc, the db might still only use one worker depending on how your tables/indexes are set up.

Comment: If you show the query, [the settings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html), the execution stats of that query you get from [`explain analyse`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html), along with `create table` and `create index` statements for the tables involved, it would be easier to discuss why your query performs the way it does.

Comment: Please share the DDL for the tables and indexes on these tables, the query itself and the result from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` for this statement. All in plain text, as an update of your question. The explain will take a while, it's executing your slow query.

Comment: @TreeWater As suggested [here](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Databases/Cloud-SQL-slow-connection-to-local-machine-1MB-s/m-p/631468) try  using the Cloud SQL Auth Proxy

Comment: What is the instance size? What is the disk size? Disk performance is directly related to disk size. If you are I/O bound, configure large disks. How large is the database(s)? Do the results fit in memory? Indexes? Your question requires a lot more information to help you.